# Interesting 3x3 table, with some unique prime numbers

Tags: mathematics, number-theory, magic-square

[image]

```
  151  131 359 131  151
    \   ^   ^   ^ /
  131 < 1   3   1 > 131
  353 < 3   5   3 > 353
  191 < 1   9   1 > 191
    /   V   V   V \  
  151  131 953 131  151
```

This 3x3 table have an interesting properties. 
Every direction  (up,down, Right, Left, 45°,135°,225°,315°) of 3 cell form prime numbers.
There are 6 unique prime numbers from this table, they are 131, 151, 191, 353, 359, 953.

Create a more interesting 3x3 table with the same rule, which there are 9 unique prime numbers from the table.

Comment: ^vote with a note: Great variation on magic squares. Just a matter of time before someone looks at [one](https://oeis.org/A002385) or [two](http://oeis.org/A006567) OEIS pages.

Comment: @humn : Every one can use those OEIS pages, then take 9 3-digit-numbers from those numbers to form the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution -

> ```
>   151  971 751 113  953
>     \   ^   ^   ^ /
>   311 < 1   1   3 > 113
>   157 < 7   5   1 > 751
>   179 < 9   7   1 > 971
>     /   V   V   V \
>   359  179 157 311  151
> ```

unique primes:

> 157 311 359 113 151 953 179 751 971

The 3 mirror equivalents (left/right, top/bottom, and corner/corner) also work.
Beyond these, there are no other solutions.